# Error al conectar C# con MySQL en Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio, odbc

tengo un problema y la verdad es que ya no sé qué más hacer.
Estoy tratando de conectar C# a MySQL
Tengo la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
cnx = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=clubdeportivo; UID=root; PWD=its2020");
```

Y al momento de ejecutar el programa me sale la siguiente ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También utilicé el driver de MySQL ODBC 8.3 Driver

```
cnx = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.3 ANSI Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=clubdeportivo; UID=root; PWD=its2020");
```

Pero me salió este otro mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé el administrador de origen de datos ODBC y sí tengo los DSN de usuario y de sistema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Que tal, al parecer alguien tuvo el mismo problema, te comparto el enlace y espero te sirva: [Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552881/iis5-odbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)